# how to restore lost sessions, bookmarks and history in Chromium

Tags: backup, snap, chromium, restore

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04LTS. I've had problems with chromium giving "not responding errors" and freezing up, and greying out. Even only 1 tab open caused the problem. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, and still had the issue. So I tried switching away from snap by adding the repositories ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4 and ppa:savoury1/chromium. I uninstalled the snap chromium from the store, and then installed chromium from the repository. When I started chromium, I found the tabs, sessions, history and bookmarks were from 2020. I closed it and uninstalled it. I reinstalled the snap chromium, only to find it had imported the 2020 history, bookmarks and sessions from the repository chromium. The result is that regardless of which version I use, I'm using an old profile instead of my working sessions and bookmarks, and history. How do I recover my old chromium profile? If it has been over-written by snap, how would I use a backup directory to restore the profile?

Comment: I suspect the moment you loaded the non-snap profile in the PPA version; its metadata was changed to have access/change date of today & thus is seen as the most current. Your *snap* profile may still be available on disk (unless you removed it with a purge) thus you can possibly return to it; what do you see in profiles in `~/snap/chromium/` ?  Do you have many to select from? the *current* is only a link you can redirect..  (*sorry I don't do it often & aren't an expert.. but have changed mine >10 times since snap chromium appeared in 2019*)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't purge, and I have two directories in ~snap/chromium. One has current pointing to it in a symlink. I deleted the symlink and pointed current to the other directory, and started chromium again. Its still stuck in 2020. If I did manage to get the ciorrect directory, how would I make it available to the PPA version? Copy it to ~/config/chromium/Default?